# Form redirecting to route on ajax request in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add ajax functionality to a like button.

Everything works, except that I get redirected to a page with json data after I click the like button.

I am using `e.preventDefault()` and it's still redirecting me.

If I use `on('click')` I get a `TokenMismatch` error in the console log even though I have included a hidden input with a token.

> jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/socialnet/public/likeStatus 500 (Internal Server Error)

If I use `on('submit')` the data goes through but I get redirected to the page with the json response.

This is in my controller `FeedController@likeStatus()`

```
public function likeStatus() {

    if (Input::has('like_status')) {
        $status = Input::get('like_status');
        $selectedStatus = Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->likes()->create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'status_id' => $status
        ]);

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'You have liked this status',
        );

        return Response::json($response);
    }
}
```

The view

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'FeedController@likeStatus', 'id' => 'like_form']) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('like_status', $status->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id) !!}
    <button type="submit" name="likeStatus" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="like-status">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like ({{ $likes_count }})
    </button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The Javascript

```
$('#like-status').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var status_id = $('input[name=like_status]').val();
    var user_id = $('input[name=user_id]').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').val()
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/socialnet/public/likeStatus',
        method: 'post',
        data: {status_id: status_id, user_id: user_id},
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** I just added the CSRF token into a variable and added it to the `data`

```
    var status_id = $('input[name=like_status]').val();
    var user_id = $('input[name=user_id]').val();
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/socialnet/public/likeStatus',
        method: 'post',
        data: {status_id: status_id, user_id: user_id, _token: CSRF_TOKEN},
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data.msg);
        }
    });
```

This gives `Status Code: 200` in the Network tab but gives `undefined` in the console and no data is going through.

**EDIT 2:** Something very weird is happening. I get `undefined` in the console when I try to like the newest status, and nothing happens. But it works when I like previous (old) status, however when I click the like button I get redirected to the json data page and data goes through.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried var_dump in PHP? Did you get anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem lies in your PHP code, it looks for like_status with

```
if (Input::has('like_status'))
```

but you send

```
{ 
 status_id: status_id, 
 user_id: user_id
}
```

There's no like_status to be found.
Input::has... will return false. Your code essentially turns into

```
public function likeStatus() {

   if (Input::has('like_status')) { //It's always false
    //
   }
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: `like_status` is `status_id` because I'm using `var status_id = $('input[name=like_status]').val()` and without the ajax, the request goes through to the database fine, the controller works.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, you have input name like_status, that why it works without ajax. But with ajax, when you send status_id = like_status, PHP will receive status_id, not like_status, if you do a 
var_dump(Input::all())
i'm sure you won't see the field like_status

Comment: You are absolutely right, can't believe I missed that. I just got the whole thing working, thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

That mean your ajax call not working at all, first make sure you have Javascript enabled in your browser and jquery is included,if its, then try to change button type submit to button, if the button is being generated dynamically you may try the live function too

```
 $('#like-button').live("click",function(){   })
```

try to debug with alert with jquery submit call to make sure the function being called

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.on('submit')` as that way you can correctly prevent the form's default action of redirecting.

As it stands you're trying to cancel a click event on `#like-status`.

Ensure that the start of your jQuery function is:

```
$('#like_form').on('submit', ...
```

Just to be extra safe to ensure that the event handlers get bound correctly you should also bind within `$(document).ready` as below:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('#like_form').on('submit', ... 

}
```

Comment: I am doing that, I changed `click` to `submit` and still getting the same error. If I grab the token with this `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` I get `undefined` in the console, but with `val()` I get `500 Internal Error`

Comment: What is the 500 Internal Service being thrown for? You can see the response from the AJAX request by right clicking in Chrome console and ticking Log XmlHttpRequests, then clicking on the response in the console. Alternatively check `laravel.log` which will list the stack trace. It could be for a CSRF mismatch, or CSRF is working and it's an error in your controller function.

Comment: Yes, this is giving `Status: 500`and laravel.log is giving `TokenMismatchException` error but I don't get it, I have the token included in the ajax request.

Comment: Try [this method](http://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/csrf-protection-with-ajax-and-laravel) of sending the token with the request rather than using `ajaxSetup`.

Comment: I don't have `filters.php` in the root dir of `app`

Comment: Actually a better option for you would be to add this hidden input into your form: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />` and that should resolve the CSRF issue.

Comment: I already have that. I'm using `Form::open()` which automatically created the hidden token field. I tried with both, the meta field and the hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line in success AJAX function

```
var new_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

to decode you data has coming from request

Comment: That didn't change anything. Still getting the same `status 500` error

Comment: Hm, i think the error with `return Response::json($response);`, So you change it to `return json_encode($response);`

Comment: what version of Laravel using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.2